# Learning advice from the Chazon Ish

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, chazon-ish, kanievsky

The Chazon Ish, in his sefer [Kovetz Igros Chazon Ish (paragraph 3)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46852&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=), mentions a certain advice concerning Torah study.

Rav Chaim Kanievsky zt"l mentions this teaching in his [Orchos Yosher](https://artscroll.com/Books/9781422622544.html) (p. 172;  יִרְאַ֣ת שָׁמַיִם):

> [...] One acquires a taste for the sweetness of Torah and its pleasantness only after learning steadily, without interruption, for three or four hours. Without that, it is difficult to achieve this spiritual level.

The Chazon Ish writes:

[image]

[image]

Thanks to @Fred for providing sources for this matter. The [Vilna Gaon](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14229&st=&pgnum=135) writes that frequent interruptions prevent a person from retaining his learning. This somewhat validates what Rav Chaim said, that you should study without interruption, for several hours in order to acquire tast for the sweetness of Torah. However, this is not completely what the Chazon Ish writes.

**Is it accepted that it is true that one will acquire a taste for the sweetness of Torah only after studying for a few hours? Any other sources that discusses this idea?**

Comment: Which teaching are you asking about? R' Chaim Kanievsky and the Chazon Ish seem to be saying two different things.

Comment: That's interesting, since Rav Chaim Kanievsky cites the Chazon Ish there.

Comment: Sanhedrin 71a: “אמר ר' זירא כל הישן בבית המדרש תורתו נעשית לו קרעים קרעים שנאמר וּקְרָעִים תַּלְבִּישׁ נוּמָה”. While Rambam (*Hil. Talmud Torah* 4:9) views R' Zeira as cautioning specifically against sleeping in a Beis Midrash due to *k’dushas beis hamidrash*, and Rashi (s.vv. "וקרעים... נעשה") views the pleasure seeking aspect of excessive sleep as the problem, the Vilna Gaon (Mishlei 23:21) understands R' Zeira as saying frequent interruptions prevent a person from retaining more than a threadbare patchwork of his learning: "שלומד תחילה ואח”כ יפסיק ואח”כ ילמוד וכן בכל יום והוא כבגד קרוע".

Comment: The Chazon Ish's point is that if a person feels reticence towards studying Torah and hopelessness that he will be able to overcome his aversion to studying diligently, he should nevertheless persist and diligently study Torah, and after awhile he will stop feeling that aversion. It seems that R' Chaim Kanievsky took this as a jumping off point for his more specific teaching about studying continuously for 3 or 4 hours before experiencing the sweetness of Torah.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Rest the question: is it true that one only can acquire sweetness in Torah study, after hours of learning?

Comment: I found some advice from the Ramak: "Though it may seem to the student that he does not understand [the material], he should nevertheless not cease studying, for his Master will faithfully cause him to discover esoteric wisdom" (Or Neerav, 3:3:8).

Comment: The link and images you bring for "Kovetz Igros Chazon Ish (paragraph 3)" are from part 2 (חלק שני). Maybe the reference is actually in part 1 of Kovetz Igros Chazon Ish. See [Ma'aseh Ish part 4, p. 67](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51557&pgnum=67) which cites "קובץ אגרות ח"**א** סי' ג". [On p. 69](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51557&pgnum=69) (the book skips p. 68) it brings a story where the Chazon Ish tells two students: "מתיקות התורה, כמה גדולה היא נעימות התורה, ואי אפשר להשיג את זה ולהגיע לזה רק אחר שקידה של שלוש וארבע שעות ברציפות בלא הפסק".

Comment: I don't see the quote [in this Hebrew edition of ארחות יושר (ch. 12 יראת שמים)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49046&pgnum=42).

Comment: @TamirEvan Thank you. So it seems that when this explanation is sources, it comes from within the circle of the Steipler?